# Flask is installed but apache returning `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`

Tags: python, apache, flask, module

I'm trying to setup wsgi and flask on my ubuntu Apache2 installation.

I installed flask to my python installation through

```
python3.10 -m pip install flask
```

I setup my flask app, and after a 500 server error I check the error.log file and find `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`

Full error log:

```
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:31.830897 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10674:tid 140023780329344] AH00489: Apache/2.4.48 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:31.831180 2022] [core:notice] [pid 10674:tid 140023780329344] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.291698 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401] mod_wsgi (pid=10675): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/search/search.wsgi'.
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.291819 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401] mod_wsgi (pid=10675): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/search/search.wsgi'.
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.292358 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.292446 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401]   File "/var/www/search/search.wsgi", line 8, in <module>
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.292465 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401]     from search import app as application
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.292492 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401]   File "/var/www/search/search/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.292505 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401]     from flask import Flask, render_template, request
[Wed Feb 23 16:41:33.292549 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 10675:tid 140023760172608] [client 192.168.0.2:50401] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

I have `#! /usr/bin/python3.10` in both my wsgi file and my `__init__.py` (flask app) file.

I only have one installation of python 3.10 on my system (at least the path to python 3.10 I pointed to has it), and it isn't found, What is going on?

EDIT 2:

Including `search.wsgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python.10

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/search/")

from search import app as application
```

However looking at it again, despite using 3.10, it looks like the package I installed `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` is still using 3.9 for some reason

Comment: Does the flask show itself in your `pip list`? but I am not sure it should be `pip install Flask` with capital F.

Comment: I'll edit my question to include full log file, as I realize there may be some other problems, but I'm sure that py3.10 has it because I used it to test the application to begin with. Also Flask was a typo sorry :( @Marya

Comment: please add your search.wsgi

Comment: @Marya OK I seem to be closer.  Apparently `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` is using python3.9 for some reason

Comment: I think it is not compatible with python 3.10 yet.
the only thing in my mind is creating a virtual env with python3.8.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the python version was running `python3` which pointed to python3.9 and not my python3.10 installation.

I installed flask to 3.9 and it still didn't work. In the end I ended up having the use of `-H` command:

`sudo -H python3 -m pip install flask`

And it worked

Comment: Man... been through tons of related threads/solution, but only this answer solved the problem for me. Still have to figure out the reason why a simple pip install is not enough though...

Comment: 6 hours I'll never get back. This is the only thing that solved it for me. I agree with @DCoder - this should be far simpler that this. For others, I was installing on AlmaLinux, ran this inside the virtualenv, and finally got it to recognize the modules.